# Error in ITK Write image

Tags: dicom, itk

I denoise an image as describe in [Pyscience](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/image-segmentation-with-python-and-simpleitk/) as follow:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

image=sitk.ReadImage("myimage.dcm")
imgSmooth = sitk.CurvatureFlow(image1=image,
                                timeStep=0.00125,
                                numberOfIterations=100)
```

And I am trying to save it as dicom file:

```
sitk.WriteImage(imgSmooth, 'denoised.dcm')
```

But I am having the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK WriteImage:     ..\..\..\..\..\ITK\Modules\IO\GDCM\src\itkGDCMImageIO.cxx:1035:
itk::ERROR: GDCMImageIO(000000000F268380): A Floating point buffer was   passed but the stored pixel type was not specified.This is currently not supported
```

I cannot in general save as dicom file using SimpleITK? How can I save my denoised image as dicom file?

Comment: Because I am facing a major problem, can someone give me some guidance?

Comment: Have you tried converting you image back to an signed short?

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to convert float to int (or uint).

```
castFilter = sitk.CastImageFilter()
castFilter.SetOutputPixelType(sitk.sitkInt16)

# Convert floating type image (imgSmooth) to int type (imgFiltered)
imgFiltered = castFilter.Execute(imgSmooth)

sitk.WriteImage(imgFiltered, 'denoised.dcm')
```